# Sequence diagram with one class and no direct connection with the operator

Tags: javascript, php, class, uml, sequence-diagram

I know that in sequence diagram I need to represent just classes between two actors but in my application I have just one class. This class is a ser.java that is going to write data in a file.txt then a php file read from this file and display the information on an interface.html using javascript file, interface.html is the interface of my app. Here the operator is not in direct relation with my class ser.java.  and the ser.java is not also in direct relation with my app there is a files bet them So, how can I represent the sequence diagram?
Thank you.

Comment: Hard to tell what you're asking. Please edit and clarify.

Comment: The actor is not in direct relation with your java but is with html, Who is itself in relation with javascript etc..  The text filé is your model, the java and PHP are both controllers and html is your view...

Comment: do I need to put html and PHP and Javscript in my calss diagramm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your terminology isn't quite right, and maybe this is the cause for your confusion.

A sequence diagram doesn't show classes between actors, but the message flow between *objects* which may have a data type that may be a class. So you'll probably have one object of your class `Ser` and other objects representing your txt, php, and html files.

As files are passive objects that don't initiate any functionality, I assume that your message flow will always start at the object that is an instance of `Ser`. Therefore, I don't think your statement that "php file read from this file" is quite precise. Who initiates the reading? In your description, only the `Ser` instance is able to do such a thing.

You are also talking about your app being different from `Ser`. So do you have an app object that must be an instance of another class? This could also be represented in your diagram.

There is no strict rule about what to include in a sequence diagram. UML is a language, and, like every language, it allows you to express your thoughts. So if you find some object relevant enough to tell about the messages it sends and receives, include it. You'll need to stop somewhere, as otherwise you'll end up describing your processor and each storage cell. In general, people tend to describe objects of classes they have written or they are directly calling from their own classes.

Comment: Ok I have a client.java send data to ser.java this ser.java write data in txt.txt and then PHP with javascript extract data from txt.txt and display them on interface.html do I need to represent this cycle and what can I call my classes?

Comment: Classes aren't mandatory. Your Java client must be an object of a class, as in Java every executable code belongs to a class. PHP and Javascript don't have classes, so an object without a class will be okay. You should name your objects according to their purpose. Not knowing the purpose of your application and of their parts, I can't give constructive advice there.